# Pass string and stringbuilder from between activities

Tags: android, string, email, android-intent

I have two activities and I need to pass some strings and a stringbuilder from TailorThreeActivity.java to EnquireActivity.java.

After displaying the string and stringbuilder data on EnquireActivity screen, I am calling an Intent to send mail by clicking on the "Send Mail" button. The "Send Mail" button will open a mail client and will set all the string and stringbuilder data as the email message body.

I am able to display the value of stringbuilder in EnquireActivity.java, but the other strings coming from TailorThreeActivity.java are not being displayed in the activity. And although the stringbuilder is being displayed in EnquireActivity, neither the strings nor the stringbuilder are displayed in the Email msg body.

This is TailorThreeActivity.java

```
package com.example.travelplanner;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TailoredthreeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView txtday1, txtmon1, txtday2, txtmon2;
    EditText et_name,et_email,et_adult,et_child,et_phone;
    Button btn;
    private int year,year1;
    private int month,month1;
    private int day,day1;
    String date1, date2;
    ArrayList<String> getChecked;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int DATE2_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tailoredthree);
        et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
        et_adult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editno_adult);
        et_child = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editno_child);
        et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editmail);
        et_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editphone);
        txtday1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdate_day);
        txtday2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdate_day1);
        txtmon1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdate_mon_year);
        txtmon2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdate_mon_year1);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_tailorthree_verify);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        year1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month1 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //get Intents

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras!=null)
            {
              getChecked = extras.getStringArrayList("list");
           }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showdate(View v) {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showdate1(View v) {
        showDialog(DATE2_DIALOG_ID);
    }


    public void updateDate() {
        final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
        String mon = MONTHS[month]; 
        txtday1.setText(""+day);
        txtmon1.setText(mon+"'"+year);
        }

    public void updateDate1() {
        final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
        String mon = MONTHS[month]; 
        txtday2.setText(""+day);
        txtmon2.setText(mon+"'"+year);
        }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datedialog = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm,
                int dd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            month = mm;
            day = dd;
            year = yy;
            date1 = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
            updateDate();
        }
    };

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datedialog2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm,
                int dd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            month1 = mm;
            day1 = dd;
            year1 = yy;
            date2 = day1+"/"+month1+"/"+year1;
            updateDate1();
        }
    };

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        //new DatePick
         switch (id) {  
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        datedialog, year, month,day);

            case DATE2_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        datedialog2, year1, month1,day1);
         }
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tailoredthree, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, EnquireActivity.class);
        i1.putExtra(et_name.getText().toString(), "name");
        i1.putExtra(et_adult.getText().toString(), "adults");
        i1.putExtra(et_child.getText().toString(), "child");
        i1.putExtra(et_email.getText().toString(), "email");
        i1.putExtra(et_phone.getText().toString(), "phone");
        i1.putExtra(date1, "datedept");
        i1.putExtra(date2, "datearr");
        i1.putStringArrayListExtra("list1", getChecked);
        startActivity(i1);
    }

}
```

This is EnquireActivity.java

```
package com.example.travelplanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EnquireActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {

    //setting var for datepicker
    private int year,year1;
    private int month,month1;
    private int day,day1;
    String date1, date2;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int DATE2_DIALOG_ID = 1;

    Button btn;
    StringBuilder stringbuilder, mailbuilder;
    String to, subject,msg;
    String getname,getadult, getchild, getmail, getphone, getdatedept, getdatearr;
    ArrayList<String> getChecked;
    CheckBox chk;
    EditText et_citylist, et_name, et_adult, et_child, et_mail, et_phone, et_datedepart, et_datearrive;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enquire);
        //registering edittexts
        et_citylist = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_city);
        et_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_name);
        et_adult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_adult);
        et_child = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_child);
        et_mail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_email);
        et_phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_phone);
        et_datearrive = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_datearrival);
        et_datedepart = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enquire_edit_datedeparture);

        //setting up email button
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnemail);
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //setting up mail content
        to = "divyangbhambhani@gmail.com";
        subject = "Tour Package Details Summary";
        msg = "Tour Enquiry Details:\nName: "+et_name.getText().toString()+"\nDestinations: "+et_citylist.getText().toString()+"\nNo. of Adult Members: "+et_adult.getText().toString()+"\nNo. of Child Members: "+et_child.getText().toString()+"\nDeparture: "+et_datedepart.getText().toString()+"\nArrival: "+et_datearrive.getText().toString()+"\nEmail: "+et_mail.getText().toString()+"\nContact No.: "+et_phone.getText().toString();

        //setting checkbox
        chk = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkenquire);
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        //setting calender components for datepicker
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        year1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month1 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day1 = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //getting Intents from previous activities

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras!=null)
            {
              getChecked = extras.getStringArrayList("list1");
              getname = extras.getString("name");
              getadult = extras.getString("adults");
              getchild = extras.getString("child");
              getmail = extras.getString("email");
              getphone = extras.getString("phone");
              getdatedept = extras.getString("datedept");
              getdatearr = extras.getString("datearr");
              stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
              for(String value:getChecked){
                  stringbuilder.append(value).append(" ");
              }
           }
        //adding citylist to edittext   
            et_citylist.setText(stringbuilder);
            et_name.setText(getname);
            et_adult.setText(getadult);
            et_child.setText(getchild);
            et_mail.setText(getmail);
            et_phone.setText(getmail);
            et_datearrive.setText(getdatearr);
            et_datedepart.setText(getdatedept);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showdate(View v) {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showdate1(View v) {
        showDialog(DATE2_DIALOG_ID);
    }

    public void updateDate() {
        final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
        String mon = MONTHS[month]; 
        et_datedepart.setText(date1);
        }

    public void updateDate1() {
        final String[] MONTHS = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
        String mon = MONTHS[month]; 
        et_datearrive.setText(date2);
        }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datedialog = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm,
                int dd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            month = mm;
            day = dd;
            year = yy;
            date1 = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
            updateDate();
        }
    };

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datedialog2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm,
                int dd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            month1 = mm;
            day1 = dd;
            year1 = yy;
            date2 = day1+"/"+month1+"/"+year1;
            updateDate1();
        }
    };

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        //new DatePick
         switch (id) {  
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        datedialog, year, month,day);

            case DATE2_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        datedialog2, year1, month1,day1);
         }
         return null;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.enquire, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Send Mail
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(chk.isChecked())
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

}
```

Comment: get text from stringbuilder and pass it as string in intent after the click of send email button

Comment: Did u try using Log.d() to find the values which are being passed to EnquireActivity.java and sent by TailorAcitivityThree.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main problems I see is this part of code

```
i1.putExtra(et_name.getText().toString(), "name");
i1.putExtra(et_adult.getText().toString(), "adults");
i1.putExtra(et_child.getText().toString(), "child");
i1.putExtra(et_email.getText().toString(), "email");
i1.putExtra(et_phone.getText().toString(), "phone");
```

with

```
getname = extras.getString("name");
getadult = extras.getString("adults");
getchild = extras.getString("child");
getmail = extras.getString("email");
getphone = extras.getString("phone");
```

You are not sending correclty these values because when you are using `putExtra` the first parameter is the key and the second is the value. That's why you are not able to retrieve them in your second activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Intent contains name-value pair do-correct in first activity**

```
 Intent i = new Intent();

 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Hello");

 i.putExtra("email", "jignesh.patel@y7mail.com"); 

 i.putExtra("sub", sb.toString());
```

Send like this..

**For Sending Mail Set these parameters..**

```
 String message = "Your_message"; String mail_id = "Email_id"; String
 sub = "Mail Subject";

 Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" +
 mail_id));

 mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,sub);
 mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mail,"Mail Using"));
```

..it will work for you..